# Algolia | Any way to return Facet and Faceted Value

Tags: javascript, algolia

We are essentially trying to build a dynamic filtering system. Where you can type a value in a facet to filter by that facet and facet value.

For example by typing 'P'. I don't want all objects where the letter 'P' exists. Instead I want all Facets where 'P' exists as a faceted value.

So using the below image as the example Facets. When typing 'P' i would like returned something similar to this.

```
{
   {value: PLOP, facet: clientName},
   {value: Poko CC, facet: clientName},
   {value: No More Period, facet: name}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can search for facet values using `searchForFacetValues()`:

```
index.searchForFacetValues({
  facetName: 'category',
  facetQuery: 'phone'
})
```

See [Search for Facet Values](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/faceting/#search-for-facet-values)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply but the issue is I would like to search in multiple facets simultaneously. This is how my current system is working where I loop through a bunch of facets and change the facetName field. but this then counts as multiple queries on algolia so we reach of QPS limit quickly

Comment: I guess if your reach your QPS limit you can upgrade plan by contacting Algolia?

Comment: You can imagine if you querying in 10 Facets and you type 5 characters per second  that is already 50 Queries per second. Having 2 users querying simultaneously will already reach the limit unless you get Algolia's business plans - which will be a bit of a stretch considering it cost $3000 per month and were just starting up...   @vvo

Comment: What framework are you using? If you were using Vue or React you could just filter through the list you receive?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasEdwards. Any chance you could attach some documentation explaining this. Using Angular 2 but if other frameworks implemented solutions maybe I can keep it in mind when staring new projects.